# WCOREDUMP(status) seems to always return true even though the feature is turned off

Tags: c, coredump

Somehow, it looks like `WCOREDUMP(status)` always tells me that a `core` file was created.

I `fork()` and when I get a `SIGCHLD` signal, I use `waitpid(...&status...);`.

Then when I use `WIFSIGNALED(status)`, I see the expected segmentation fault with `WTERMSIG(status)` (code 11) and somehow I also get true when I call `WCOREDUMP(status)`.

However, by default Ubuntu is setup to not generate a core dump file. How come `WCOREDUMP()` still returns true? (unless the `core` file is saved somewhere else than in the current directory?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the core dump file is generated by the kernel and sent to the apport application. The information is found in `man 5 core` which has a section:

> **Piping core dumps to a program**

This program is defined in `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` and on most Ubuntu systems, looks like this:

```
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P
```

This means pipe the core dump data to application apport, which in turn may decide to send the data to a file if

1. the program that crashed is not one which is to be reported to Ubuntu; **and**
2. the ulimit of your process is larger than zero.

So, as far as the kernel is concerned, the core dump was generated and thus `WCOREDUMP()` returning true is sensible.